# laravel 4 group collection/results

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do a simple group by 'alpha' in my loop for a glossary page but not sure how to achieve this.  My data is

alpha glossary_title

A Apple B Banana A Another Apple!

GlossaryController.php

```
public function index() {

  $glossary = Glossary::groupBy('alpha')->orderBy('glossary_title', 'asc')->get();
  return View::make('glossary')->with('glossary', $glossary);

}
```

migration

```
Schema::create('glossary', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
             // columns
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('glossary_title');
            $table->text('glossary_desc')->nullable();
            $table->char('alpha', 1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

glossary.blade.php

```
@foreach($glossary as $glossary)
        <li>{{ $glossary->glossary_title}} <br /> {{ $glossary->glossary_desc}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a new collection groupped by `$glossary->alpha`:

```
$glossary = Glossary::orderBy('glossary_title', 'asc')->get();
$glossary = $glossary->groupBy('alpha');

// same as this:
$glossary = $glossary->groupBy(function ($entry) {
  return $entry->alpha;
});
```

You will need 2 loops in your view then, first for groups, second for entries in each group.